# Detect losing multicast stream

Tags: c, linux, networking, multicast

I'm programming for a device to receive the multicast stream from a server (worked properly) and I want to check whether the device loses/drops multicast stream in operation (not solved yet).

The device joins a multicast group using `setsockopt()` and receives the multicast packets successfully. Then, I saved the value of the socket descriptor (1) which was used to join multicast group, and the value of the interested multicast group address (2).

I call `getsockopt()` in a thread to detect losing multicast stream every second. (**this is just pseudo code, not the full code**)

```c
static int sd;
static ip_mreq group;

static void _checkMulticastThread(void)
{
    int optlen;

    while (1) {
        sleep(1000);

        if (sd < 0) {
            printf("The device hasn't joined multicast group yet\n");
            goto err;
        }

        // Get multicast state:
        optlen = sizeof(group);
        ret = getsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, &optlen); // value of sd and group are got from (1) and (2)
        if (ret == 0) {
            printf("still join\n");
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("drop multicast stream, errno = %d\n", errno);
        }
    err:
        printf("end proc\n");
    }
}
```

It seems like the way I implemented this is not correct: the program crashes after executing `getsockopt()` and I even do not have a chance to get `errno`'s value.

Please show me the correct way to check whether the device loses/drops multicast stream.

Comment: There is no such thiing as a 'multicast stream; and therefore no such thing as 'losing' it either. But your question is actually not about that, it is about the crash calling `getsockopt()`, which was pointless in the first place as nobody has changed the state. Don't think for a moment that calling it is going to tell you anything about the non-existent 'multicast stream'. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

After going trough the kernel implementation in [ip_sockglue.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9ff9b0d392ea08090cd1780fb196f36dbb586529/net/ipv4/ip_sockglue.c),

I can see that there is no implementation for the `IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP` option in the `do_ip_getsockopt` function, so the call to the option is invalid. However, this doesn't explain the crash.

As it looks from the kernel code, once the member is added, stays in the group unless the socket is closed, or explicit call to IP_DEL_MEMBERSHIP is executed.

You can try `getsocketopt()` for `IP_MULTICAST_IF` or `IP_MULTICAST_ALL` to get more insights of the socket.

Comment: I call `getsockopt()` to check whether the device loses/drops multicast stream, not to get any addresses

Comment: @xuanduc611 But that's not what it is for, or what it actually does.